# Using querySnapshot.size as .doc id with firebase and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Hello I would like to make an order system. So I got my number of items in the database. I transformed it with the variable OrderID. But when I try to put it as a doc id, I get this error: u.indexOf is not a function

```
const Orders = () => {

    fire.firestore().collection("orders").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {      
    console.log(querySnapshot.size); 

    var OrderID = querySnapshot.size; 
    console.log(OrderID);

     fire.firestore().collection("orders").doc({OrderID}).set({
        marque: Marque,
        nomproduit: NomProduit
      });
    });
    
  };
```

If anyone have a solution? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the `.collection()` call before it, `.doc()` expects a string value. Instead, you are trying to pass an object that you've created by using `{}` around `OrderID`.

While it's not immediately clear to me why you're changing the snapshot size into a document ID, if that's really what you want to do, you could do this:

```
.doc(`${OrderID}`)
```

The above would use string template to put the `number` inside a string.

Comment: I use it to make an ordering system to display it in Var OrderID = querySnapshot.size + 1; Thanks for solution!

Comment: You might want to consider creating/storing unique IDs for your orders. Building them sequentially like this has a lot of potential to lead to bugs (like if one is deleted, for example).

Comment: You're absolutely right, it was enough to insert it as a value, it's much simpler and it avoids bugs, thank you very much!